# Is it possible to disable ECHO when using socket for telnet?

Tags: c#, sockets

Can I stop server from echo every command i send to it?
This is part of my code:

```
 Socket s = ConnectSocket(server, port);

 if (s == null)
   return ("Connection failed");

 int bytes = 0;
 string ret = "";

 bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, SocketFlags.None);
 ret = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
 //ret="????!????BCM96358 xDSL Router\r\nLogin: "
 ret = ret.Substring(12); //Remove the telnet header: 255,253,1,255, 253, 33,255, 251, 1,255, 251, 3 
//IAC,DO,Echo, IAC,DO,Remote Flow Control, IAC,WILL,Echo, IAC,WILL,Suppress Go Ahead

  request = "Admin\r\n";
  bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
  s.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);

  bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, SocketFlags.None);
  ret = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
//ret = "Admin\r\nPassword: "
```

Answer (score 2):

For me sending this sequence has solved problem of echo.

```
"\xFF\xFB\x01\xFF\xFB\x03"
```

in other words it's equal to `IAC WILL ECHO IAC WILL SUPPRESS-GO-AHEAD`

Comment: The reason why this works can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12421999/655404 "The solution most commonly used is actually to say that _you_ will do the echoing, which will make the other end stop doing echoing"

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it *is* echoing? Have a look at what's happening at the network level using [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org). I strongly suspect that the echo is occurring at the client, not the server.

Comment: hen I access it via telnet , i don't get this response.

Comment: @jullin: I don't understand what you mean. You haven't really explained what you're seeing. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints